# Obtain a reference of Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Project loaded from ProjectFile in netstandard

Tags: roslyn, .net-standard, roslyn-code-analysis

I try to port some code to netstandard so it can run on Linux.

Previosly I used MSBuildWorkspace to optain a workspace and load a Project.

```
MSBuildWorkspace workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Project project = await workspace.OpenProjectAsync(projectPath);
```

When I switched to netstandard there was no longer a MSBuildWorkspace. How do I get a `Project` instance file from a `.csproj` file.

---

**EDIT**

That's the project file with all packages I reference.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core" Version="15.5.180" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis" Version="2.6.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp" Version="2.6.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces" Version="2.6.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.Common" Version="2.6.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel" Version="1.0.0-rc3-1-003177" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: thanks that the information I needed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSBuildWorkspace will be included in a seperate package. See this [issue](http://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/23011)